# Ruby Float Round Error Bug?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, floating-point, rounding-error

I am getting the following **rounding error** when I try to Unit test the class below:

```
class TypeTotal
    attr_reader  :cr_amount,  :dr_amount,
                 :cr_count,  :dr_count

    def initialize()
        @cr_amount=Float(0);    @dr_amount=Float(0)
        @cr_count=0;            @dr_count= 0
    end

    def increment(is_a_credit, amount, count=1)
        case is_a_credit        
         when true
            @cr_amount = Float(amount)+ Float(@cr_amount)
            @cr_count += count
         when false
            @dr_amount = Float(amount)+ Float(@dr_amount)
            @dr_count += count
        end
    end
end
```

Unit Test:

```
require_relative 'total_type'
require 'test/unit'

class TestTotalType < Test::Unit::TestCase 
  #rounding error
  def test_increment_count()
    t = TypeTotal.new()
       t.increment(false, 22.22, 2)       
       t.increment(false, 7.31, 3) 
     assert_equal(t.dr_amount, 29.53)    
  end
end
```

Output:

```
  1) Failure:
test_increment_count(TestTotalType) [total_type_test.rb:10]:
<29.529999999999998> expected but was
<29.53>.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I am using **Floats** because it was recommended in the Pick Ax book for dollar values because they shouldn't be effective by round errors.

I am running on `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]` on Windows 7 64-bit Home and Windows XP 32-bit Pro.

I've tried

- casting my variables to floats
- removing += and spelling out increment

The behavior appears random:

- 12.22 + 7.31  works
- **11.11 + 7.31  doesn't work**
- 11.111 + 7.31 works

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: Whatever you do, [don't file it as a bug!](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/HowToReject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use Big Decimal:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

class TypeTotal
    attr_reader  :cr_amount,  :dr_amount,
                 :cr_count,  :dr_count

    def initialize()
        @cr_amount=BigDecimal.new("0");  @cr_count=0,
        @dr_amount=BigDecimal.new("0");  @dr_count=0

    end

    def increment(is_a_credit, amount, count=1)
        bd_amount = BigDecimal.new(amount)
        case is_a_credit        
         when true
            @cr_amount= bd_amount.add(@cr_amount, 14)
            @cr_count += count
         when false
            @dr_amount= bd_amount.add(@dr_amount, 14)
            @dr_count = count
        end
    end
```

The Pick Ax (p53) book used float for currency as an example but had a foot note explaining that you need to either add .5 cent to when you display the value or use Big Decimal.

Thanks for are your help!

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that was the advice given? I'd expect the advice to be *not* to use Floats, precisely because they use binary floating point arithmetic, and so *are* prone to rounding errors. From the [Float documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Float.html):

> Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation.

If you could quote the exact advice you're referring to, that would help.

I would suggest you use [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead, or use an integer with implicit units of "cents" or "hundreds of a cent" or something similar.

Comment: Can't believed I missed the footnote explaining why the example was wrong... I guess it shows you should code on well rested brain :)

Answer (score 2):

The problems with float are already mentioned.

When you test with floats, you should not use `assert_equal` but `assert_in_delta`.

Example:

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestTotalType < Test::Unit::TestCase 
  TOLERANCE = 1E-10 #or another (small) value

  #rounding error
  def test_increment_count()
    t = TypeTotal.new()
       t.increment(false, 22.22, 2)       
       t.increment(false, 7.31, 3) 
     #~ assert_equal(t.dr_amount, 29.53)  #may detect float problems
     assert_in_delta(t.dr_amount, 29.53, TOLERANCE)    
  end
end
```